# Image is not rendering in DynamicReports

Tags: java, dynamic-reports

I am trying to render image in a column in DynamicReport.But it is not rendering
I have tried following way.
First I built a  column

```
  @Override
    public ComponentColumnBuilder designImageColumn(ReportVO input, String columnName) throws ReportEngineException {

            DynamicReportVO dynamicReport = input.getDynamicReport();
            Map<String, DynamicColumnVO> columns = dynamicReport.getColumnsMap();

            DynamicColumnVO column = columns.get(columnName);

            BODataTypeBuilder boDataTypeBuilder = new BODataTypeBuilder();
            ImageBuilder image = null;

            if(column.getName().equals("Image ")){
                image = cmp.image(new ImageExpression()).setFixedDimension(150, 150);
                LOGGER.info("ImageBuilder created " + image);
            }

            ComponentColumnBuilder componentColumnBuilder = null; 

            ColumnBuilders col = new ColumnBuilders();
            componentColumnBuilder=col.componentColumn(column.getTitle(), image); 


            LOGGER.info("componentColumnBuilder created and returning.. " + componentColumnBuilder);

            return componentColumnBuilder;
        }
```

---

### Then I built a Image Expression class to evaluate the column

```
public class ImageExpression extends AbstractSimpleExpression<InputStream>{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public InputStream evaluate(ReportParameters reportParameters) {

  return new ByteArrayInputStream((byte[]) reportParameters.getValue("Image"));
    }
}
```

But I am not getting the value of Image in ReportParameters in imageExpression. Due to that  it is throwing source evaluating error. Any lead will be helpful. Thanks in Advance